# SMTP is not sending all emails in gmail business account

Tags: php, smtp

I am using SMTP to send out 1000 of emails in a **loop**. But Gmail sends only 50 emails.

I have business account with Gmail. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using scripting language to send mail via Gmail (business account), you can send 100 mails per day.
The [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en) to see the details.
You can send mass mails using mailgun, they are free for the first 10000 mails.